# Form Variable Passing

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am using Javascript to pass form variables to the PHP page `sprcial_action.php` but it is not redirecting to that page. My code is given below, please tell me where is the problem?

```
<script>
function formSubmit(index)
{
    var image = document.getElementById("hdnimage" + index);
    var email = document.getElementById("email" + index);

    window.location.href = "sprcial_action.php?name=" + image; 
}
</script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1" name="form1" method="get">

<div class="offers">

    <div class="offer-banner">
         <img src="/images/specialoffer/offer-1.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="mobile">
         <input type="text" value="Mobile" name="mobile" />
    </div>
    <div class="or-button"></div>
    <div class="email">
         <input type="text" value="Email Address" name="email" id="email0"  />
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="hdnimage0" id="hdnimage0" value="/images/specialoffer/offer-1.png" />
    <div class="redem-copon">
         <!--<a href="#"><img src="/images/specialoffer/copun.png" /></a>-->
         <input type="image" src="/images/specialoffer/copun.png" onclick="formSubmit(0)" />
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: my page name is sprcial_action.php not special_action.php

Answer (score 2):

`window.location.href` needs full path starting with `http://`. and add `.value` to image object

you should be writing as

```
window.location.href = "http://mydomain.com/sprcial_action.php?name=" + image.value;
```

Comment: +1. Also not canceling default behavior may be the second half of the problem (after this navigation).

Answer (score 1):

Your `image` variable refers to the `input` **object**, not its value. To get its value, add `.value`:

```
window.location.href = "sprcial_action.php?name=" + image.value;
// here -------------------------------------------------^
```

But note that you're getting the `email` field but not then doing anything with it, and setting the `href` does not *submit* a form, it just takes you to the given page.

If you want to change the location the form submits to, you have to set the `action` property on the `form` object (and not change `location.href`):

```
var form = document.getElementById("form1");
form.action = image.value;
```

I'm not 100% certain you can change that *during* a form submit reliably across browsers, you'll need to test on your target browsers.

Answer (score 1):

If 'sprcial_action.php' page is in the same application then please refer to the above answer(@Rab'a Answer), you have to use image.value instead of image( As it will be treated as a object). You don't need to give the full path.
But if this page is outside the current application then you have to specify the full address.

window.location.href = "http://imagesheaven.com/sprcial_action.php?name=" + image.value;

Try using document.location.href also. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

have the answer:

```
 <script>
function formSubmit(index)
{
    var image = document.getElementById("hdnimage" + index);
    var email = document.getElementById("email" + index);
var data=image.value;
    window.location.href = "http://yourservername/sprcial_action.php?name=" + data; 
}
</script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1" name="form1" method="get">

<div class="offers">

    <div class="offer-banner">
         <img src="/images/specialoffer/offer-1.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="mobile">
         <input type="text" value="Mobile" name="mobile" />
    </div>
    <div class="or-button"></div>
    <div class="email">
         <input type="text" value="Email Address" name="email" id="email0"  />
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="hdnimage0" id="hdnimage0" value="/images/specialoffer/offer-1.png" />
    <div class="redem-copon">
         <!--<a href="#"><img src="/images/specialoffer/copun.png" /></a>-->
         <input type="image" src="/images/specialoffer/copun.png" onclick="formSubmit(0)" />
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```